# how can I open & close apps in android using Python

Tags: android, python, python-2.7

I have "tpacketCapture" application on my android-phone.

I want to open it (start capture) and close it (end capture) by using a Python-Script on my mobile.

Thanks in advance

Comment: any particular reason why it has to be python?

Comment: You can check out http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2009/06/introducing-android-scripting.html, it might help

Comment: The reason is that i have script in Python that posting message and i want to add this option to the script

Comment: You can check out QPython as well, but I'm not sure if it will let you launch applications or not. http://qpython.com/

Comment: Their wiki seems to be down though, but the app in the play store seems to have good reviews.

Comment: Furthermore, does the tpacketCapture app start capturing the moment it is opened, and save it when it is closed?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your phone is rooted, applications do not have access to stop/close other running applications, regardless of the method in which they are opened.